# Custom modal CanDeactivate Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem.

I have follow an example to custom modal in my CanDeactivate`.

But it's not working for me...

I have create a stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgs93u

I have tried to use `ngx-bootstrap` and services

Someone could you explain me why it doesn't work please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Stackblitz shows missing providers for at least the guard and the modal service. Please fix all the console errors first. set providers within app.component.ts